# Cleaning up density plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I would like to smooth up the edges of my graph here. Is there a way to get `geom_density2d` and/or `stat_density2d` to interpolate a bit differently to remove these apparent discontinuities?

[image]

I used this to create the included example:

```
  ggplot(data = PlotModel1, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Conc), shape = "") +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), n = 100, geom="polygon", contour = TRUE) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

I would like a smoother plot like this 
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you include some data so that your problem can be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here:
[non-overlapping polygons in ggplot density2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150753/non-overlapping-polygons-in-ggplot-density2d?rq=1)

Basically, you can extend the x,y limits to allow the polygons to be fully drawn.

Then, if that makes the plot too zoomed out, you set limits with coord_cartesian:

[r stat_contour incorrect fill with polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257951/r-stat-contour-incorrect-fill-with-polygon)

So, for your code, it will be something like:

```
  ggplot(data = PlotModel1, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Conc), shape = "") +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), n = 100, geom="polygon", contour = TRUE)+
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()+
  xlim(-150, -50)+
  ylim(30, 45)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-110, -80),ylim=c(33, 41))
```